# select all xml nodes which contain a certain attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have to select all nodes which contain an attribute with a certain name.

This is my current, not working approach.

```
public List<string> RetrieveValuesForAttribute(string attributeName)
{
    var list = new List<string>();

    string xpath = "//*[@Name='" + attributeName + "']";
    XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = document.SelectNodes(xpath);

    foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodeList)
    {
        list.Add(xmlNode.Attributes[attributeName].InnerText);
    }

    return list;
}
```

I try to select all nodes which contain the attribute with the name given in the method parameter `attributeName` and add the value the variable `list`.

*Example:*

This method call:

```
List<string> result = RetrieveValuesForAttribute("itemSelectedHandler");
```

Should return an list which contains the string "OnSelectedRelatedContactChanged"

This is the xml file:

```
<GroupBoxWrapper id="gbRelatedContacts" text="Related Contacts">
  <TabIndex>0</TabIndex>
  <TabStop>false</TabStop>
  <PanelWrapper id="pnlRelatedContactsView" width="1350">
    <TabIndex>0</TabIndex>
    <TabStop>false</TabStop>
    <ListViewWrapper id="lvRelatedContacts" itemSelectedHandler="OnSelectedRelatedContactChanged" itemDoubleClickHandler="OnRelatedContactDoubleClick">
      <TabIndex>0</TabIndex>
      <TabStop>true</TabStop>
      <ListViewColumns>
        <Column title="Name" mapNode="Contact\Name" />
        <Column title="Lastname" mapNode="Contact\Lastname" />
      </ListViewColumns>
    </ListViewWrapper>
  </PanelWrapper>
</GroupBoxWrapper>
```

Further questions:
Would it be better to solve this with LINQ?

**Solution 1:** thank you, ywm

```
public List<string> RetrieveValuesForAttribute(string attributeName)
{
    var list = new List<string>();

    string xpath = @"//*[@" + attributeName + "]";
    XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = document.SelectNodes(xpath);

    foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodeList)
    {
        list.Add(xmlNode.Attributes[attributeName].InnerText);
    }

    return list;
}
```

**Solution 2:** thank you, Jon Skeet

```
public List<string> RetrieveValuesForAttribute(string attributeName)
{
    //document is an XDocument
    return document.Descendants()
                   .Attributes(attributeName)
                   .Select(x => x.Value)
                   .ToList();
}
```

The LINQ to XML Solution looks far more elegant to me.

Comment: I would definitely use LINQ to XML for this. Can you make `document` an `XDocument` instead?

Comment: Yes i can, i will try it with LINQ to XML

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you could use LINQ to XML for this, it would be utterly trivial:

```
// Note that there's an implicit conversion from string to XName,
// but this would let you specify a namespaced version if you want.
public List<string> RetrieveValuesForAttribute(XName attributeName)
{
    // Assume document is an XDocument
    return document.Descendants()
                   .Attributes(attributeName)
                   .Select(x => x.Value)
                   .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The XPath you are looking for should be

```
"//*[@" + attributeName + "]"
```

What your original XPath was doing was looking for all elements that have a `Name` attribute with the value `attributeName`

This will look for any element which has an attribute with attributeName

```
//*[@title]
```

would return the column elements

Comment: Thank you, for your solution it works fine. But i like the LINQ to XML approach more.

Answer (score 3):

Im not  sure about the C# syntax but I think the xpath  vlaue is wrong.
Please try: "//*[@itemSelectedHandler]".
What should in c#

```
  string xpath = "//*[@" + attributeName + "]";
```